# Vaccum hash from xml throws Null pointer in code, but renders fine in json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using vaccum to fetch product details from Amazon Product Advertising API.
    req = Vacuum.new

```
    req.configure(key: configatron.api.amazon.productAPI.key,
              secret: configatron.api.amazon.productAPI.secret,
              tag:    'biz-val')

    regex =  Regexp.new "http://([^/]+)/([\\w-]+/)?(dp|gp/product|exec/obidos/asin)/(\\w+/)?(\\w{10})"
    productID=regex.match(@url).captures[4];
    host=regex.match(@url).captures[0];
    utype=regex.match(@url).captures[2];

    @url="http://#{host}/#{utype}/#{productID}"
        params = { 'Operation'   => 'ItemLookup',
           'ItemId' => productID,
           'ResponseGroup'=>'Large'
          }

    res = req.get(:query => params)
    hsh=Hash.from_xml(res.body)
    @details=hsh
    item=hsh[:ItemLookupResponse][:Items][:Item]#Throws an Undefined method [] for nilClass
```

You can ignore the regex parsing. I have checked it works fine.The hash that is generated from res.body is a valid hash, it shows up fine in the json rendered(@details), but throws a nilClass thing when I try to access it in the code.
I think thi might be because`hsh[:ItemLookupResponse]` returns something other than a hash. I am not sure what it is returning though. How do I access :Items ?

Comment: Can you some logging like this `logger.log pp(hsh)` and post the output in the log file

Answer (score 0):

If it says you are trying to call `[]` on a `NilClass` then it is highly likely that you are. On that particular line you call `[]` on these three

```
hsh
hsh[:ItemLookupResponse]
hsh[:ItemLookupResponse][:Items]
```

So one of them is, again highly likely, to be `nil`.  You might want to use debugger/repl and put a breakpoint right before the erring line and examine `hsh`.  I use [pry](http://pryrepl.org/), with which you woud first `require 'pry'` and then put `binding.pry` where you want the breakpoint.